# AutoIt using _IEFormElementGetCollection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, autoit

I am trying to select a button and submit by index instead of by name in AutoIt. The reason why I can't use _IEFormElementGetObjByName is because there are two buttons on the page, and they both have the same name when I inspect element:

Button 1: `<input type="submit" name="fsubmit" value="New Upload">"`

Button 2: `<input type="submit" name="fsubmit" value="Return to Login Page">`

I need to differentiate between the two when selecting one or the other. I'm fairly sure I am supposed to be using _IEFormElementGetCollection to select the button by the form element index number. If there is another way that will work, I'm open to suggestions as well.

Thanks!

Edit: Here's what I ended up doing, it seems to work fairly well.

```
Local $oIE = _IEAttach("WEBSITE NAME")
Local $oForm = _IEFormGetCollection($oIE, 0)
; _IEFormElementGetCollection 4 is New Upload, use caution!
Local $oSubmit = _IEFormElementGetCollection($oForm, 4)
; Set to focus only for now, when ready to really upload, change "focus" to "click"
_IEAction($oSubmit, "focus")
_IELoadWait($oIE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most secure way in this situation will be,

```
Local $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "input")
For $oInput In $oInputs
    if $oInput.name == "fsubmit" And $oInput.value == "Return to Login Page" Then
        ; your code here
    Endif
Next
```

Or, as you suggested,

```
_IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "input", 1); returns second input
```